# Content approval - customize labels of radio button options

Tags: content-approval

I have an on-premise install of SharePoint and want to edit the Content Approval options window seen once one clicks Approve/Reject on an item. I want to keep all of the same functionality, and just want to indicate "Approved." instead of "Approved. This item will become visible to all users." I have backed up approve.aspx and taken a look at it but the label descriptions seem to be stored elsewhere. can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Maureen